# why can't I programmatically set the imageurl on an Image control?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET 2010 app and am trying something very simple. I use Image control through out and basically wanted to say, before I assign an image to it (from a class) look for the image; if it's not there, use the default no_image jpeg I have. I have verified the image is there ad nauseam. If I set the property in the IDE to point to this image, it'll display. However, if I set it programmatically, even if I hard-code the path programmatically, it doesn't show.

Forgettign about getting the proper path and all that, (of which Ive tried several things) I can;t even hard code the relative path. Here I copied & pasted the relative path from the properties window...

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/UploadedPictures/Users/no_profile_picture.jpg"
```

This doesn't work. It translates into src="../../UploadedPictures/Users/no_profile_picture.jpg" which is correct but the image doesn't display.

If I hardcode the absolute path it doesn't work either...

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myApp\UploadedPictures\Users\no_profile_picture.jpg"
```

Comment: What is the path being rendered in the browser?

Comment: src="../../UploadedPictures/Users/no_profile_picture.jpg"   that is correct....up 2 levels than down through UploadedPictures/Users/. The image is there.

Comment: Right Click on Image on your Browser page and See Properties- Copy the Location text and paste in new browser and see if the Image is displayed. Where are you setting the image-path, in the codebehind file of the page?

Comment: @Killroy do what @TimSchmelter suggested or run Fiddler to watch the img request on the wire. You're probably getting a 404 or 500 error. You'll be able to inspect that error in Fiddler, or if you go to the image url directly as Tim suggested

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a virtual path. Try adding `~` before your path.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/UploadedPictures/Users/no_profile_picture.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks but that was a typo on my part. The ~ is in there in the code.